# What is well-known port number of P2P applications?

Tags: networking, p2p, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I have some trace files (truncated `tcpdump` file) contains traffic of a network. I want to separate packets of P2P applications such as `BitTorrent`,`Skype`,etc.

Does any one have a list of well-known port number of P2P applications? I want these port numbers to filter packets with appropriate application.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: It's general list. You must know all p2p applications name and then check its port number in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that easy. Emule used to use port 4662 for TCP and 4672 for UDP connections. They as well as all other p2p-based programs including torrent clients have since then started to use automatic port assignment to make it harder to block traffic. Furthermore, both emule and torrents have been using protocol encryption for years now, making it even harder to use packet inspection to find these packets.

Skype is especially known for getting even through firewalls, so there's no real port to block here since it supports options to move to port 80 and 443 if need be and you can't really filter that out. Skype also uses encryption making things harder once again.

You'd need filter packets by packet inspection to be efficient here, but as already said, if the client used encryption there's basically nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, p2p networks don't have dedicated specific ports and use them dynamically, because the end stations are mostly connected to multiple other end stations. So they are using the ports from the range of not well known ports.

Comment: This isn't really accurate. Outgoing connections use dynamic high-range port numbers, but this is true for any protocal, e.g. HTTP. The port that the client opens for incoming connections must be fixed. In HTTP this is always 80, but Bittorrent and many other protocols allow the client to choose its own server port. Most clients these days choose a random port to make what the OP is doing impossible.

Comment: That's what I ment.